# params data binding in Grails unit test of a service class

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have a service method that takes params as an input and creates a domain class passing in params for auto binding. Testing of this is simple by specifying params as a map of key value pairs. However, I don't know how to simulate an array of associated objects in the params map.

I observed client side sending in params in the following format:

```
["description":"abc",  "subTask[0].name": "first subtask name"]
```

How do I mock this type of params? Since this is not a controller test I can not use mockParams AFAIK.

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not creating the array?

Comment: Getting an error complaining that "subTask[0].name" is not a valid property. Typically the data binding classes would convert this into an associated object property, but looks like that's not happening in a unit test.

Comment: a unit test shouldn't act differently.  Are passing the map in using the constructor args (new Foo(mockParams))?

Comment: no, mockParams is not available in a GrailsUnitTestCase vs ControllerUnitTestCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be this:
Since controller params map parsing is not available in a Service class you have to convert values and objects on your own. So in my example I have to manually create an array of associated objects within the params map. Here is an example:

```
  def params = [ state: "Open", type: "Cable", 
            needByDate: new Date("Fri May 11 00:00:00 PDT 2012"),
            //"subTasks[0]":["name":"ABC"]  //no workie
            "subTasks": [new Task("name": "ABC")]
  ]
  mockDomain(Task.class)
  Task task= service.saveNewRequest(params)
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The params map in Grails does magic stuff with parameter names that contain dots, making them available in the controller as "sub-maps".  For example if you have parameters a.b=1 and a.c=2 you can ask for `params.a` and get a map `[b:1, c:2]`.  So try something like this:

```
["description":"abc",  "subTask[0]":["name": "first subtask name"]]
```